# How to load the last three added data from sub pages into home page

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a page contains cards with title and image and descriptions, and I can add as much as I want, then I want to load this data in home page but I need it to shows only the last 3 added on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the content of your cards is powered by an `apostrophe-pieces` subclass you want to use `apostrophe-pieces-widgets` to dynamically pull the last 3 pieces and add them to any page (in your case the home page).

This tutorial details getting up and running with `apostrophe-pieces-widgets`
https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces#displaying-pieces-with-widgets

After you have your widget in your template, you want to configure the widget to Select from All.. and limit it to 3.

[image: Apostrophe pieces widget's configuration to pull most recently added]

You can demo the editing experience of this type of widget by visiting the [Apostrophe Open Museum demo](http://demo.apostrophecms.org) and working with the below widget, which is on the home page

[image: Apostrophe Open Museum example of a pieces widget]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it didn't work :(
I am sure that I am doing something wrong but I can't figure where it is

Comment: From your question it isn't clear what your configuration actually is. I would recommend reading the entire Getting Started with Pieces tutorial and think about your content in terms of Pages and Pieces https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces

And/Or pull down the Apostrophe Open Museum project and read its docs and start from there https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-open-museum

Comment: Thank you @Stuart Romanek it worked after I followed the documentation.